# siamltex + todonotes package

Tags: todonotes

Quite simply, I would like to render a todo-list at the beginning of an article I am working on.  I am using the siamltex document class, however, which seems to get in the way somehow.

Here is a MWE:

```
    \documentclass[draft]{siamltex}
    \usepackage{todonotes}

    \begin{document}
    \listoftodos

    I love cats.  Cats are great.  I wish I could write my thesis on cats. \todo{Mention again how amazing cats are.}

    I wish I could be a cat.  They just eat, sleep, poop, and sometimes vomit.  And then there's the petting.  It's like a 24/7 massage.  \todo[inline]{Schedule a massage for yourself pronto.}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

I have to use the siamltex document class, so simply changing the class is not an option.

For reference, here is the .tdo file:

```
    \contentsline {todo}{Mention again how amazing cats are.}{1}{section*.2}
    \contentsline {todo}{Schedule a massage for yourself pronto.}{1}{section*.3}
```

Comment: No errors, no warnings.  But no todo list is generated at the beginning of the document.  It works for a class like article.  And siamltex is not usually built-in, but it is commonly used in the math community: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siam?lang=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `siamltex` class sets `tocdepth` to 0, but you need it at 1. There's another small problem, because the section titles are set inline. I wouldn't bother about the indentation of the title, since this is just for drafts.

```
\documentclass{siamltex}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\listoftodos}{\@starttoc}{\mbox{}\par\@starttoc}{}{}
\makeatother
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\listoftodos

\bigskip

I love cats.  Cats are great.  I wish I could write my
thesis on cats. \todo{Mention again how amazing cats are.}

I wish I could be a cat.  They just eat, sleep, poop, and
sometimes vomit.  And then there's the petting.  It's like
a 24/7 massage.  \todo[inline]{Schedule a massage for yourself pronto.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have no idea how much this helps. Now I can finally get organized and finish my cat thesis.